# Android Studio is not installing app into device

Tags: android, android-studio

My device is running android Lollipop 5.1 with Developers Options enabled and USB Debugging option checked. When I hit the RUN button on Android Studio it shows the following in the event log:

```
Target device: qmobile-lt500-D5180B1R63091071
Installing APK: C:\Users\Umair\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
Uploading file to: /data/local/tmp/com.example.umair.myapplication
Installing com.example.umair.myapplication
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.umair.myapplication"
```

And then nothing happens. App doesn't install and open. When I click on Android Monitor, it shows events on logcat, my device name etc. confirming that it is properly connected.
Someone tell me where the problem is.

Comment: Do you have enough memory space to install the app? That may be the issue.

Comment: Try to uninstall it from your device if you already have it installed. Try cleaning and rebuilding the project. Also, try to close and reopen the Android Studio. Sometimes these kind of bug occur. One thing that also occurs with me sometimes is when the Android Studio install the app but doesn't launch it. Could you check if it was installed but not opened?

Comment: Are there previous versions of the app? You may need to uninstall

Comment: Yes I have. Actually it's just a "Hello World" program.

Comment: Clean and rebuild project and try again, also did you try running the app on an emulator?

Comment: I have checked installed apps on my phone. It is not in the list

Comment: Emulator runs the app.

Comment: as a curiosity what phone do you have and what API?

Answer (score 1):

In your mobile check unknowns sources apk install on/off
And make sure in your device space is available

Answer (score 0):

First uninstall app from your device if you've already installed it.
Then in your IDE do clean and rebuild,and try restarting the device and also restarting your IDE.
That should work as expected now